# Creating breakpoints using the Polymer app-grid layout

Tags: layout, polymer, media-queries, polymer-1.0, grid-layout

The app-grid Element (helper class)in Polymer allows to create a responsive grid layout. The given [Polymer Example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-grid) creates a layout with three list items placed horizontally next to each other.

To make it responsively change the grid from 3 columns to 1 on smaller screens, breakpoints have to be declared. The documentation talks about defining custom properties inside a @media rule. (Link above)

I can't get the media rules to make the change.
I found similar questions about the @media rule in Polymer but answers always pointed out to go with the iron-media-query. Now that the Polymer documentation mentions the @media I believe there must be a way to do it.

I tried using it like so but couldn't get it to work:

```
  <style include="app-grid-style">
   :host {
      --app-grid-columns: 3;
      --app-grid-item-height: 200px;
      --app-grid-gutter: 20px;
   }
   @media (max-width: 600px) {
      :host {
         --app-grid-columns: 1;
      }
   }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [demos](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-grid/demo/simple-responsive-grid.html#L103) they always call `this.updateStyles` when the window is resized, to make sure all custom properties are applied correctly.

Unfortunately this information is missing from the docs...

```
  attached: function() {
    this._updateGridStyles = this._updateGridStyles || function() {
      this.updateStyles();
    }.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._updateGridStyles);
  },

  detached: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this._updateGridStyles);
  }
```

If you are using app-grid outside of an element in your main document you would have to call `Polymer.updateStyles()` instead.